# Save quiver plot with tikzplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, tikz

I want to save a quiver plot using tikzplotlib. 
Here is a MWE:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x,y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-2, 2, .2), np.arange(-2, 2, .25))
z = x*np.exp(-x**2 - y**2)
v, u = np.gradient(z, .2, .2)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
q = ax.quiver(x,y,u,v)
import tikzplotlib

tikzplotlib.save("2delete.tex")
```

I get an error like this:

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tikzplotlib/_patch.py", line 69, in <genexpr>
    yield tuple(seq[i % len(seq)] for seq in seqs)
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

Does anybody know this problem and a workaround?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From GitHub [repository](https://github.com/nschloe/tikzplotlib):

```
Of course, not all figures produced by matplotlib can be converted without error
```

Instead of load plot directly into tex you can load saved image.

Comment: Thank you for the attempt. However, displaying the figure before saving it resets the current figure. Calling `plt.show(block=False)` results in the same error.

Comment: @gumpel not all plots are converted by this package. See update